# Can I use Nintendo 3DS in a flight operated by China Eastern?

Tags: airlines, electronic-items, china-eastern

In China Eastern, you are prohibited to use a smartphone during a flight, even after a leaving phase, and also even if you set it to flight mode.

In fact I saw many passangers instructed to stop using it by a flight attendant. Also, when I used my Walkman (an iPod-like portable music player), I was asked if it is a smartphone. I explained it is a walkman, and then was allowed to use it.

However, how about using a Nintendo 3DS? As the latest series of Pokemon was released recently, I definitely want to play it during my flight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Chinese government currently (November 2016) bans the use of mobile phones in flight - even if they are in "Flight mode".  There are rumors that this will change soon, but at the moment it is the case.

Other electronics ARE allowed during flight, although depending on the airline they may not be allowed during takeoff and landing.

So yes, your Nintendo 3DS will be fine to use after takeoff and before landing.

Comment: Thanks. But this restriction of mobile phones didn't happen in my flight on Air China (May, 2016). Also it didn't happen in other (non-Chinese) airlines arriving at or leaving from airports in China (July and October, 2016).

Comment: As far as I know the law only applies to Chinese carriers, not foreign airlines.  Enforcement, as with many of these laws, is mixed and will depend on the specific crew.  I've flown 4 flights on Chinese carriers in the past 6 weeks, and every time it was mentioned multiple times that phones must be turned off for the entire flight - but it was never really enforced.

Answer (score 1):

I asked multiple clerks at the check-in counter just in case I won't get instructed to stop using it during a flight.

They answered that it is only a smartphone that is prohibited to use during a flight. A portable gaming device like Nintendo 3DS or Sony PSVita are allowed to use as well as a laptop.

However, as is the case in other airlines, I wasn't be allowed to use it during takeoff and landing.

Comment: Little unfriendly to write your own answer and mark it as correct, when there is already an answer that was equally correct...  :(  Especially given that your answer includes incorrect information (with most other airlines you WOULD be allowed use this device during takeoff and landing)

Comment: @Doc Hmmm... The reason I didn't accept it is because it lacked evidence. So I relied on my trial and then reported it. But your point is valid enough; I'll give it to you. Thanks.

Comment: My "evidence" is exactly the same as yours - experience flying Chinese airlines!